# Symfony - ManyToMany - replaces instead of adding

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many, symfony5

I apologize in advance if my question seems silly to you, I'm a beginner, I've searched but I can't find the answers.

We are in a factory. In this factory, each worker can have several posts, and each posts can contain several workers. So we are in a ManyToMany relationship. The problem is that when I add a worker to a post, he doesn't add to the worker already present in this post, he replaces him! As if a post could only contain one worker.
Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong or send me precisely the documentation related to this type of problem?
Thanks.
Here is the related code.

(Poste = Post, Operateur = Worker)

**in the Post Entity :**

```
     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Operateur::class, inversedBy="postes")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="poste_operateur")
     */
    private $operateurs;

     /**
     * @return Collection|Operateur[]
     */
    public function getOperateurs(): Collection
    {
        return $this->operateurs;
    }

    public function addOperateur(Operateur $operateur): self
    {
        if (!$this->operateurs->contains($operateur)) {
            $this->operateurs[] = $operateur;
            $operateur->addPoste($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeOperateur(Operateur $operateur): self
    {
        $this->operateurs->removeElement($operateur);
        $operateur->removePoste($this);

        return $this;
    }
```

**In the Operateur (worker) entity :**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Poste::class, mappedBy="operateurs")
 */
private $postes;


/**
* @return Collection|Poste[]
*/
public function getPostes(): Collection
{
    return $this->postes;
}

public function addPoste(Poste $poste): self
{
    if (!$this->postes->contains($poste)) {
        $this->postes[] = $poste;
        $poste->addOperateur($this);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function removePoste(Poste $poste): self
{
    if ($this->postes->removeElement($poste)) {
        $poste->removeOperateur($this);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

**In the PosteController, method to add an operateur to a post :**

```
/**
 * @Route("/{id}/new", name="poste_ope", methods={"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function addOpe(Request $request, Poste $poste): Response
{
    $form = $this->createForm(PosteType2::class, $poste);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

        $this->addFlash(
            'success',
            "L'opérateur a bien été ajouté au poste {$poste->getNom()}  !"
        );
        return $this->redirectToRoute('operateur_index');
    }

    return $this->render('poste/addope.html.twig', [
        'poste' => $poste,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

**The form in PostType2 :**

```
class PosteType2 extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('operateurs', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Operateur::class, 
                'label' => 'ajouter un opérateur à ce poste',
                'choice_label' => 'nom',
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
            ])
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, [
                'label' => 'Enregistrer',
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'btn btn-primary'
                ]
            ]);
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Poste::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you try replace `$this->postes[] = $poste;` by `$this->postes->add($poste);` ?

Comment: Do you have constructors in each class with $this->operateurs = new ArrayCollection() in Post and $this->postes = new ArrayCollection() in Operateurs?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the PosteController, here is the correction :

[add an addPost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcLUZ.png)

Here is the documentation who helped me : https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html#saving-related-entities